# IP address reuse on macvlan devices

Tags: linux, lxc

I'm trying to create easy to use and possibly simple testing environment for some product and got some strange behaviour of macvlan's.

What I'm trying to achieve: make a toolset for one-line start/stop of lxc containers(via docker) bound to external ip(I have enough of it on host machine).

So, I'm doing something like this:

```
docker run -d -name=container_name container_image
pipework eth1 container_name ip/prefix_len@gateway
```

and pipework here does this:

```
GUEST_IFNAME=ph$NSPID$eth1

ip link add link eth1 dev $GUEST_IFNAME type macvlan mode bridge
ip link set eth1 up
ip link set $GUEST_IFNAME netns $NSPID

ip netns exec $NSPID ip link set $GUEST_IFNAME name eth1
ip netns exec $NSPID ip addr add $IPADDR dev eth1
ip netns exec $NSPID ip route delete default 
ip netns exec $NSPID ip link set eth1 up
ip netns exec $NSPID ip route replace default via $GATEWAY

ip netns exec $NSPID arping -c 1 -A -I eth1 $IPADDR
```

And it works for **first** time per IP. But for second time and later packets for containers IP isn't getting into container, while all configuration seem fine.

So it looks like this:

External machine

```
➤ ping 212.76.131.212
....silence....
```

Host machine

```
root@ubuntu:~# ip link show eth1
2: eth1:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:17:c9:e1:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

root@ubuntu:~# ip addr show eth1
2: eth1:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:17:c9:e1:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

root@ubuntu:~# tcpdump -v -i eth1 icmp
tcpdump: WARNING: eth1: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
00:00:46.542042 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 9623, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    5.134.221.98 > 212.76.131.212: ICMP echo request, id 6718, seq 2345, length 64
00:00:47.549969 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 9624, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    5.134.221.98 > 212.76.131.212: ICMP echo request, id 6718, seq 2346, length 64
00:00:48.558143 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 9625, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    5.134.221.98 > 212.76.131.212: ICMP echo request, id 6718, seq 2347, length 64
00:00:49.566319 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 9626, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    5.134.221.98 > 212.76.131.212: ICMP echo request, id 6718, seq 2348, length 64
00:00:50.573999 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 9627, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    5.134.221.98 > 212.76.131.212: ICMP echo request, id 6718, seq 2349, length 64
^C
5 packets captured
5 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
1 packet dropped by interface
```

Host machine, netns of container

```
root@ubuntu:~# ip netns exec 32053 ip link show eth1
48: eth1@if2:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether b2:12:f7:cc:a1:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root@ubuntu:~# ip netns exec 32053 ip addr show eth1
48: eth1@if2:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether b2:12:f7:cc:a1:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 212.76.131.212/29 scope global eth1
    inet6 fe80::b012:f7ff:fecc:a19d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@ubuntu:~# ip netns exec 32053 tcpdump -v -i eth1 icmp
tcpdump: listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
....silence....
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

So, can anyone say, what can it be? Can this be caused by **not** a bug in macvlan implementation? Is there any tools I can use to debug that configuration?

Comment: Looks like it is ARP caching issue in our environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an ARP cache issue.

ARP cache on gateway was holding entry for IP with MAC of already dead macvlan and was not updating by just `arping`.

Solved by adding

```
ip netns exec $NSPID ping -c 1 -I eth1 $GATEWAY
```

to the end of `pipework` script. This ping forces gateway to update ARP cache entry/